# NoClassDefFoundError exception for SNIHostName

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

when calling 
new SNIHostName(url.getHost()
i got the exception 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/net/ssl/SNIHostName

Answer (score 0):

i should define my IDE to work with JRE 8...